# Java: What should be done with abstract methods that are only in the superclass in the UML diagram?

Tags: java, inheritance, abstract

I have the below UML diagram:[image: Class Diagram]
I've read that abstract methods should be overridden by a subclass. How should I override `calculateMonthlyPay()` when there is no `calculateMonthlyPay()` in either subclass? Can I create methods that aren't shown in the UML diagram?

Here is my code for `Employee` and its subclasses `PartTimeEmp` and `FullTimeEmp` for reference.

```
public abstract class Employee {
    Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);
    public String name;
    public String ID;

    //Employee constructor
    public Employee(String name, String ID) {
        this.name = name;
        this.ID =  ID;
    }

    //ID setter
    public void setID(String ID) {
        ID = keyboard.nextLine();
        this.ID = ID;
    }

    //name getter
    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public abstract String getStatus();

    public abstract double calculateMonthlyPay();

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "Employee{" + "name=" + name + ", ID=" + ID + '}';
    }
}

class PartTimeEmp extends Employee {
    public double hourlyRate;
    public int hoursPerWeek;
    //PartTimeEmp constructor
    public PartTimeEmp(String name, String ID){
        super(name, ID);
    }

    public void setHours(int hoursPerWeek) {
        this.hoursPerWeek = hoursPerWeek;
    }

    public void setRate(double hourlyRate) {
        this.hourlyRate = hourlyRate;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "PartTimeEmp{" + "hourlyRate=" + hourlyRate + ", hoursPerWeek=" + hoursPerWeek + '}';
    }
}

class FullTimeEmp extends Employee {
    double salary;

    //FullTimeEmp constructor
    public FullTimeEmp(String name, String ID) {
        super(name, ID);
    }

    //Set salary of employee
    public void setSalary(double salary) {
        this.salary = salary;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "FullTimeEmp{" + "salary=" + salary + '}';
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The UML diagram shows each method only in the class that first introduced it. Otherwise, each class's UML would show all the methods of all the ancestor classes of its hierarchy, which wouldn't be very convenient.

So you should definitely override `calculateMonthlyPay()` and `getStatus()` in the sub-classes, or you wouldn't be able to compile your code.

Comment: That's great, thanks! Do you have any idea what `getStatus()` should do?

Comment: @PeadarÓDuinnín I have no idea, since there's no documentation. Your guess is as good as mine :)

Comment: That's grand. Thanks again! :)

Answer (score 1):

Since `PartTimeEmp` instances are instances of `Employee`, such instances must have all of the methods defined in `Employee` defined.

Since UML is not used to define these implementation details, the implementation of the methods may be either in `Employee` or any of its subclasses to which the instance belongs. But it must exist.

Answer (score 1):

if you are implementing a concrete class extending from abstract class, **you have** to implement all abstract method.

If you can't change the abstract class (modify signature etc), only option left out for you is to implementing if.

```
class PartTimeEmp extends Employee {
    public double hourlyRate;
    public int hoursPerWeek;
    //PartTimeEmp constructor
    public PartTimeEmp(String name, String ID){
        super(name, ID);
    }

    :
    :
    public double calculateMonthlyPay() {
        // do noting
        // if you can change the method *calculateMonthlyPay*, you could have thro' some exception here
        return 0;
    }
```